# Setting HTML5 canvas display properties with JavaScript makes canvas invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a game in HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript, and I am making my canvas as such:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

And in my JavaScript:

```
var canvas;

function myFunction() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    canvas.style.display = "block";
}
```

And I want my canvas to appear when I run `myFunction()`, so I have this CSS:

```
canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

However, when I run `myFunction()`, I get the sounds from my game, which means the canvas is on the page, however the canvas is not displayed. Even if I apply this CSS:

```
canvas {
    display: none;
    border: 10px solid lime;
}
```

And run `myFunction()`, I see nothing on the page. What am I doing wrong here? Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: did you inspect what your code does?, i think display: block gets overwritten by a none with !important or something

Comment: @RamondeVries Of course, the styles inspector!

Comment: @RamondeVries Yes, I figured it out - I had an overriding statement in inline HTML. Please can you add your comment as an answer for future reference?

Comment: @RamondeVries If you add your answer, I will mark it as accepted and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inspect what your code does?,
I think display: block gets overwritten by a none with !important or something.

If so, change your script code or try to remove the overwriting !important tag when its not necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, I should have spotted the obvious myself.

Comment: @JackBashford, no problem. Im glad you found your answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

remove css  `canvas {display: none;}` instead on page load

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
canvas.style.display = "none";
```

and when u calling function it will be display block

Answer (score 1):

Change at the last block of your code, You are using `display: none` which terminate the canvas

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid lime;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I start with `canvas {display: none;}`, and then I set it to `block` using JavaScript however this is breaking my canvas. I don't want to have the canvas start out visible, I want it to become visible when a function executes

Comment: Okay might be I misunderstood, could you please tell me when you are running myFunction()

Comment: On a button click